# Best In Place : Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

I'm trying to implement the Best In Place Gem on one of my views. However, when I click a sample button, nothing happens, and Chrome inspect pops out the error --

**Update**
You can take a look at an example here -- >

https://fierce-meadow-1536.herokuapp.com/users/10/common_apps/6/edit

```
username: tester@tester.com
password: 123123
```

--

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function best_in_place.js?body=1:52
Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function best_in_place.js?body=1:595
```

The specific javascript in reference (Above the #comment)-->

```
  this.oldValue = this.isNil() ? "" : this.element.html();
    this.display_value = to_display;
    jQuery(this.activator).unbind("click", this.clickHandler);
    #Uncaught TypeError: Property 'jQuery' of object [object Object] is not a function 
    this.activateForm();
    this.element.trigger(jQuery.Event("best_in_place:activate"));
  },
```

This is my Application.js file --

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require jquery_nested_form
//= require best_in_place
//= require_tree .
```

My view --

```
== best_in_place @common_app, :cover_letter, :path => user_common_app_path(@user,@common_app),  :type => :textarea
```

Users.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
  $('.best_in_place').best_in_place()
```

What is happening?

Comment: this is because gem supports different version of jquery than one you are using

Comment: Hey Pandurang, I tried popping in a lower version of jQuery, but the error still persisted. Not sure what to do.

Comment: I ended up going with x-editable-rails, a newer gem, but more frequently updated.https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a fix, it seems like activity on the gem has declined quite a bit.

Ended up finding a rails adaptation for x-editable, -- https://github.com/werein/x-editable-rails

It is new, so be aware of it, but it worked well and developer is very active on it.